# Stubbed method not consistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a  test Im trying to create I create two employee objects.

```
employee_1 = create :employee
employee_2 = create :employee
```

Then I stub a method called `has_salary?` on each

```
  allow(employee_1).to receive(:has_salary?).and_return(false)
  allow(employee_2).to receive(:has_salary?).and_return(true)
```

Now if I have a byebug statement inside the test and I run

```
employee_2.has_salary?
```

this gives `true`

But

```
Employee.first.has_salary?
Employee.second.has_salary?
```

both give `false`

why is the behavior non-consistent? And what should be done to stub the method for the object throughout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior isn't inconsistent. Your expectations here are just completely wrong.

When you stub a method you're replacing the method on *that* object with a stub.

When you call `Employee.first` it creates a SQL query to fetch the first row off the table and it then instanciates a completely new Employee instance which is hydrated with the values from the database. Even though this represents the same row in the database as the object created by your factory they are completely different objects in memory.

> And what should be done to stub the method for the object throughout?

Depends on what you're actually testing. If you need to insert your stubbed object into for example a controller you could stub the class method:

```
 allow(Employee).to receive(:first).and_return(employee_1)
```

Or perhaps you should just be assigning your factory instance to a variable or `let/let!`.